# Get data from Laravel Eloquent object?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to add some more data to Eloquent model object before passing to view/json.

```
$company = Company::with("users")->get();
```

I want to add few more data with `$company`,my tries code is below,

```
$company->data->client_count = User::where('status', '=', 1)->count();
```

But it is not working,Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add data to `$company`. you can make it an array and pass the value 
`$company[] = Company::with("users")->get();`

`$company[] = User::where('status', '=', 1)->count();`

Answer (score 0):

Try This Hope it working

```
$company['count'] = User::where('status', '=', 1)->count();
```

Then Check the result.

Answer (score 0):

the with method accepts an array.
static Builder|Model with(array|string $relations)
meaning you can say Model::with(['one','two'])->get();